# Creating a bijection between integers and a set of strings

Tags: python

I have a set of unique strings, I want to create a unique integer identifier for each string.

**Usage** I want a function to move back and forth, if I give it an integer it returns the corresponding string and vice versa.

Here is how I am doing it

```py
def str_to_int(S):
    integers = list(range(len(S)))
    my_dict = dict(zip(S,integers))
    rev_dict = dict(zip(integers,S))
    return my_dict, rev_dict
```

If I need to get the integer identifier of an item of `S`, I need to call the function and then the appropriate returned dictionary.

I want something simpler, given an integer or a string, it knows, somehow automatically if it's an int or str and return the other identifier (i.e. if I give an int it returns the str identifier and vice versa). Is it possible to do it in a single function ? (if possible without being obliged to recreate dictionaries for each call)

Edit: I thought of doing to functions `str_to_int(S:set, string:str)->int` and `int_to_str(S:set ,integer:int)->str` but the problem is 1) that's two functions, 2) each time two dictionaries are created.

Answer (score 4):

Since what you want is something a little more complicated than what a normal dictionary can do, I think you want to encapsulate all of this in a class that behaves the way you want the dict to behave.  You can make it "look like" a dict by implementing `__getitem__`, something like:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Set, Union, overload


class StringTable:
    """Associate strings with unique integer IDs."""

    def __init__(self, strings: Set[str]):
        """Initialize the string table with the given set of strings."""
        self._keys: List[str] = []
        self._ids: Dict[str, int] = {}
        for key in strings:
            self._ids[key] = len(self._keys)
            self._keys.append(key)

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, o: int) -> str: ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, o: str) -> int: ...

    def __getitem__(self, o: Union[int, str]) -> Union[str, int]:
        """Accepts either a string or int and returns its counterpart."""
        if isinstance(o, int):
            return self._keys[o]
        elif isinstance(o, str):
            return self._ids[o]
        else:
            raise TypeError("Bad argument!")

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._keys)
```

Now you can use it like:

```
strings = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}
bijection = StringTable(strings)
for s in strings:
    print(s, bijection[s])
    assert bijection[bijection[s]] == s
```

etc.

Comment: Didn't know about `overload` and that usage of `Ellipsis`, nice!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you insist on doing this only with a single function, but we surely can. Also, just pass in the prebuilt dictionaries so that you don't need to build them on every call.

```
def build_mapping(S):
    integers = list(range(len(S)))
    return dict(zip(S, integers)), dict(zip(integers, S))

def get_value(key, conv, rev_conv):
    return conv[key] if isinstance(key, str) else rev_conv[key]

S = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'hello', 'world']
conv, rev_conv = build_mapping(S)

key = 'hello'
key2 = 3

# print "3 hello"
print(get_value(key, conv, rev_conv), get_value(key2, conv, rev_conv))
```

Comment: I thought it's more readable using a single function and it's less lines of code. But, I guess, you don't recommend it.  Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are strings and ints, they can't collide, so they can go in the same dict.

```
strings = ['one', 'alpha', 'blue']

# mapping from strings to ints and ints to strings
two_way_dict = {}
for i,s in enumerate(strings):
    two_way_dict.update([(s,i), (i,s)])

bijection = two_way_dict.get

#example
bijection('alpha') -> 1
bijection(1) -> 'alpha'
```